# Change the version of the embedded tomcat using spring starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

The requirement is to use spring boot version 2.2.6.RELEASE however the tomcat version should be 9.0.37.

I tried to do it by excluding the tomcat starter from the `spring-boot-starter-web` depdendency like so :

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

And added the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` separately which has the 9.0.37 tomcat version :

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

However even after doing so the version is not override and the following gets used :

```
Mar 11 2020 09:31:38 UTC
Apache Tomcat/9.0.33
9.0.33.0
```

Do we need to do anything else to override the tomcat version?
Is it possible to override it by excluding started?

Update:
The parent pom is a corporate parent pom and not the spring-boot-starter-parent. As per one of the answers we can simply override the tomcat.version property however my effective pom doesn't show it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change embedded tomcat's version in existing spring boot app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192295/how-to-change-embedded-tomcats-version-in-existing-spring-boot-app)

Comment: Don't. Never mix modules of different versions of a framework, that will lead to issues. Just change the version as explained in the reference guide [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/#using-parent-pom) for a list of version properties to override see [this appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dependency-versions-properties)

Comment: Great I think this is the way to do it. Will try it today!

Comment: Its just not working :-( Is there a sample application demo for this somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not inheriting from `spring-boot-starter-parent` I can only guess that you import `spring-boot-dependencies` in your dependencies management somewhere.

The [documentation covers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/#using-import) what you need to do to override the tomcat version. Each tomcat artifact should be listed with the overridden version, before you imports `spring-boot-dependencies`. The list of artifacts can be found in [`spring-boot-dependencies`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.2.6.RELEASE/pom).

Using a different version of the starter is wrong (you can't mix two Spring Boot versions in the same app) and will have no effect since dependency management is in control anyway. In other words, you'll get `spring-boot-starter-web` version `2.3.2.RELEASE` indeed but all the artefacts that it brings will be managed by the dependency management (the tomcat version defined by version `2.2.6.RELEASE`).

In that particular case of yours, upgrading to `2.2.9.RELEASE` could also be an option as it provides dependency management for the tomcat version that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I get it.

Comment: Just one thing, I added all the required tomcat dependencies in the dependency management tag and it worked. Just that it doesn't matter if I add it before the spring boot dependencies import dependency or after, in both cases I am able to override the tomcat version. However the documentation states that it should before the spring boot dependencies tag. Any reason why we have to add it before the tag or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this has been already answered.

For you, as you are using maven, you need to override the properties **set in parent Spring pom.**

```
<properties>
  ......
<tomcat.version>your_version</tomcat.version>
  ......
<properties>
```

For gradle, it is simple as

```
ext['tomcat.version'] = '8.5.34'
```

in your main build.gradle

Source: [How to change embedded tomcat's version in existing spring boot app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192295/how-to-change-embedded-tomcats-version-in-existing-spring-boot-app)

Comment: The effective pom doesn't have any property namely tomcat.version and simply overriding it doesn't work for me. May be it was available in older versions of spring boot i.e. is before boot 2.

Comment: It seems that it is still the same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826247/how-should-i-change-tomcat-version-of-a-war-in-spring-boot-project

But I am using Gradle for most parts so I can't help that much

Comment: Oh its there when I manually traverse the poms and check in spring-boot-dependencies pom then I can see the property. But it doesn't show up in effective pom. We have a company wide parent pom as our parent pom instead of spring parent as the parent (which is there as a dependency) does that make a difference? I though it combines the properties of all poms.

Comment: I would suggest for that company parent to add parent to `spring-boot-starter-parent`. Then you can edit the version - that is probably why it is not working for you.

Comment: You mean the company poms parent should be changed to spring-boot-starter-parent?

Comment: No, no, the main parent should be linked to spring parent via 
`<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>`

Comment: We cant change the parent pom as its not in our control and multiple project use it. The second comment on the question post seems to be the way to go. Its not working for me but will check in more detail today.

Comment: Alright, make sure to let me know what was the problem, I would love to know :)